# What will happen if an X shape wings mounted on biplane?

Tags: aircraft-design

[image]The question is What will happen  if an X shape wings mounted on a light biplane? What will happen in the place which upper wings come closer to lower wing?

Comment: What do you mean by "X-shaped wings"? Do you mean wings that are angled away from each other, so that they are closer together near the fuselage, and farther apart away from the fuselage? And do you have a more specific question than "what will happen"? Because as far as I know, the answer is going to be something along the lines of "it will fly".

Answer (score 6):

Drawing from the hypothetical of "could a starwars X-Wing fly" which is [brilliantly answered by James Gull here](https://www.quora.com/Whats-wrong-with-an-X-wing-aircraft-in-real-life-Would-one-be-able-to-fly-Would-it-be-aerodynamic-Would-it-be-easy-to-control) it is possible to achieve flight in this configuration

> ...It's not a very aerodynamic design. All **those intersections at the
>   fuselage will create a ton of drag due to interfering aerodynamics**.
>   The engines and wingtip pylons are not helping in that regard either,
>   as they are not well blended in. The wings are essentially a biplane
>   configuration, which definitely works. The designer would need to take
>   extra care near the fuselage due to the surfaces being so close
>   together; **their wakes would interfere with each other. Careful tuning
>   could help turn this into somewhat of an advantage in slow flight.**

The [Strop SP-7 was an early proposed design for such an aircraft](https://retromechanix.com/stroop-x-wing-convertible-speed-planes-1935-9/nggallery/image/model-of-stroop-sp-6-as-biplane). But it only 
remained in this configuration for takeoff and slower flight segments, the wings folded into a mono plane configuration for high speed cruise. I cant find any evidence that it ever actually took flight.

Some aerodynamic ["trials" have been done on the "design"](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/testing-aerodynamics-star-wars-ships-virtual-wind-tunnel).

If you are asking about an "X" looking from the top down, it appears that [Sikorsky dreamed up something like that and went as far as running tests on the design as well as building some of the major components](https://www.sikorskyarchives.com/X-WING.php) but the project was ultimately canceled and it never flew.

Comment: Seen head-on, the Rutan Quickie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_Quickie could almost qualify as an X-wing.